# Почему анахронизм КАРЕТА СКОРОЙ ПОМОЩИ употребляется в наше время?

Tags: грамотная-речь, этимология, выбор-слов

В советские годы ни разу не встречал в художественной литературе или в теленовостях, передачах применительно к современности слово КАРЕТА СКОРОЙ ПОМОЩИ, а только машина "Скорой помощи". Внезапно лет 15 тому назад как стали ВСЮДУ писать и говорить "карета "Скорой помощи", имея в виду машину "Скорой помощи". Карета "Скорой помощи" - это анахронизм, относящийся к эпохе карет, а не 21 века. Почему так произошло для меня загадка.

Comment: Тысяча извинений,но и при Советской власти у образованных людей было в ходу выражение КАРЕТА СКОРОЙ ПОМОЩИ.

Answer (score 7):

Видимо, потому что в 21 веке стал сильнее интерес к истории, а это всё-таки символ, история службы. В советское время такие архаизмы были как бы даже под запретом (как относящиеся к капиталистическому прошлому, к богатым), а сейчас на  всё старинное даже как бы мода, большой спрос, вот и вытащили на белый свет. Карета скорой помощи возвращает нашу память к истокам службы, к 19 веку, в начале двадцатого были кареты уже на резиновом ходу, но фургонами их называть некрасиво - так и были "кареты", выражение стало своеобразным фразеологизмом - символом. И звучит красиво, и стариной отдаёт. Почему нет? В быту по-прежнему просто "скорая помощь" или "скорая", а в публицистике красиво - "карета скорой помощи".

Answer (score 1):

Космический корабль, морской лайнер... *Карета скорой помощи*, как и *приёмный покой* — фразеологизмы. Их, фразеологизмов, век долог, а именно эти термины появились (по историческим меркам) совсем недавно — лет 120 как. Пики частотности употребления КСП случались и в 60-е, и в 80-е годы.

Answer (score 0):

С ***каретой скорой помощи*** не всё так просто.  Вот попробуйте определить область применения и стиль этого выражения.

**Фразеологизм?** Но фразеологизмы характерны для разговорной речи, а вы вряд ли услышите на улице такую фразу: "Скорее вызовите карету скорой помощи".

**Устаревшее выражение?** Тоже нет, его можно встретить в современной публицистике и в художественной литературе, причем в совершенно нейтральном значении, безо всякой иронии или шутливости , характерных для подобных случаев.

Вскоре подоспели ГАИ и карета «скорой помощи». [Происшествия (1997) // «Столица», 1997.05.27]

Куда-то с визгом промчалась карета скорой помощи. [Владимир Войнович. Москва 2042 (1986)]

**Может быть, высокий стиль,** тяга к старине и т.д. Опять же ничего подобного, пишется в самых обычных текстах.

**Тогда термин?** Нет вроде бы, официально это совсем не карета, а **автомобиль скорой помощи.**

**Обсуждение темы**  [https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/Обсуждение:карета_скорой_помощи](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5:%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B8)

**Мне лично это выражение кажется каким-то недоразумением:** как будто появилась чья-то инициатива для официального названия (пилотный проект), но не была одобрена. Или что-то в этом роде.

Comment: Думаю, что источник обычный - тележурналистика (в разговорах не слышал). Редкий случай, когда "находка" представителей этой среды не вызывает у меня протеста. В новостях мне такое название нравится больше, чем "автомобиль скорой помощи".

Comment: Тогда уж лучше "машина скорой помощи", по крайней мере  не раздражает слух (фонетика аналогичная, а автомобиль сложно произносить). А то официально - автомобиль, у  журналистов - карета, а  в разговорной речи - ни того ни другого, одни вопросы в Интернете по поводу кареты. И что с ней делать, каков ее статус?Это что,  сленг? В словаре такое значение не зафиксировано.